# Is there a way to install apt packages which doesnt require root permissions atleast, without sudo rights, and inside the home folder?

Tags: apt, permissions, dpkg

Like `virtualenv` in python, Is there a way to create a custom environment inside the home folder ( atleast for installing apt packages ), and without requiring sudo rights, and also without assuming that any packages be installed already by the root ?

I have explored docker and even [docker-rootless](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#prerequisites), but even docker-rootless still needs `newuidmap` and `newgidmap` to be installed in the system. Even if that can be installed, the bottleneck can be from the fact that the user must have atleast 65536 UIDs/GIDs per user.

Somewhere [chroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot) was recommended, but apparently that too requires administrative privileges to setup.

I noticed that Flatpak has some [features](https://github.com/flatpak/flatpak/issues/1576) like this, but there are 2 issues with that too.

1. It requires flatpak to be installed by the root
2. It doesn't have most apt packages.

I ask this for 2 main reasons.

1. To install `apt` packages in my home directory instead of root in my own laptop ( with sudo rights )
2. To install packages that doesnt necessarily do anything that requires sudo rights, but still needs `apt` to install. `apt download` just doesn't cut it, as we have to manually deal with the dependencies and configuration etc.

Is there a reason why nothing like `virtualenv` was attempted for `apt` ?

Comment: Seems very similar to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42567/how-to-install-program-locally-without-sudo-privileges.

Answer (score 1):

You may download the package directly with apt, and extract the files with dpkg, but with most bigger programs, you have to manually adjust tons of config files to match the different environment.

```
apt download <apt package name>
dpkg -x <package file name> <destination directory>
```

For example:

```
apt download x11-apps
dpkg -x x11-apps_7.7+7_amd64.deb ./
```

Comment: Like i mentioned `apt download` doesnt cut it due to the fact that i might have to do everything including configs myself.

Comment: The only easy to use but crap solution is to use `apt show snapd`, which will create an entire virtual machine just to run you 1KiB app. If it's that what you want, you are free to go, but don't expect any help from any serious Linux admin.

Comment: to run `apt download` you must have run `apt update`. If not you still need root access for that